# C# Expression.Lambda cannot be compiled at runtime

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have build expression parser `CreateExpression()` which return constructed Expression Tree

```cs
Expression rule = CreateExpression(_BuyRuleString);
LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(rule, _ParameterExpressions);
var func = lambda.Compile();
```

but it failed when I call `lambda.Compile()` with the error

`variable 't1' of type 'System.Int32' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined`

So I print out expression `lambda`

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`9[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Double,System.Double,System.Boolean[]]>(
System.Int32 $t1,
System.Int32 $t2,
System.Int32 $t3,
System.Int32 $t4,
System.Int32 $t5,
System.Int32 $t6,
System.Double $r1,
System.Double $r2) {
.Call SwarmTrader.ExpressionParser.SeriesOperatorFunc.GTZ(.Call SwarmTrader.Indicator.RSI(
        $t1,
        "p"))
}
```

which equivalent to

```cs
Expression<Func<int, int, int, int, int, int, double, double, bool[]>> test = (t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, r1, r2) => SwarmTrader.ExpressionParser.SeriesOperatorFunc.GTZ(SwarmTrader.Indicator.RSI(t1, "p"));
```

But `var func = test.Compile();` works. So I try resolve it in combination ...

```cs
lambda = Expression.Lambda(rule, _ParameterExpressions); // lambda.Compile() failed
lambda = Expression.Lambda(test.Body, _ParameterExpressions); // lambda.Compile() failed
lambda = Expression.Lambda(rule, test.Parameters); // lambda.Compile() failed
lambda = Expression.Lambda(test.Body, test.Parameters); // lambda.Compile() works
```

Can anyone point out why `lambda.Compile()` does work only from `test`?

Comment: Could you show what is in rule and _ParameterExpressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely your `CreateExpression()` does not reference parameters that are in `_ParameterExpressions`, but defines its own instead. You have to use *same* `ParameterExpression` in expression tree you're compiling and in lambda arguments.

Comment: So it does not reference by parameter name but instance of `ParameterExpression`?